# Dynamic SQL Query to find the count of missing values for all column of a table

Tags: sql-server

I want to write a dynamic sql query to find out the count of missing value for each column from a table. The table comprises of 40 columns and writing missing count for each column is lengthy so can we do it dynamically? I tried to write dynamic query as provided below, but got an error as

> Must declare the scalar variable "@sql"

Query:

```
Declare @sql nvarchar(max)  
Declare @columnlist nvarchar(max)   
Declare @FieldName nvarchar(max)    

set @columnlist = 'Column 1,Column2 ,Column3 ,Column4 ,Column5 ,Column6 ,Column7 ,Column8 ,Column9 ,Column10 ,Column11 ,Column12,Column13'  

set @FieldName = 'Column 1,Column2 ,Column3 ,Column4 ,Column5 ,Column6 ,Column7 ,Column8 ,Column9 ,Column10 ,Column11 ,Column12,Column13'

set @sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*)-COUNT(' + @columnlist + ') as '+ @FieldName +'from table_name' 

exec (@sql)
```

Comment: You have a typo. The second query `set @FieldName` doesn't have a starting single quote in it.

Comment: try with `"" double quote` with `select query`

Comment: @NisargShah I have updated that but still getting the same ereror

Comment: what you have update?

Comment: @BhargavChudasama Do you meant by syntax as : set sql = "SELECT COUNT(*)-COUNT(" + columnlist + ") as "+ FieldName + "from Table_name"

Comment: you share exact error ?

Comment: I think that writing down (using "copy&paste") the 40 expressions will be faster than writing down the lis of fields twice and then build code that transforms a column list string into some kind of table expression to then be able to dynamically build the list of expressions.

Comment: @BhargavChudasama  I run the query as provided in above question, and i am getting an error as 'Must declare the scalar variable "sql".'

Comment: You must not highlight and execute the parts of the script separately. Run it as a whole to receive the next error message (something like "syntax error, ')' expected".

Comment: @WolfgangKais when i execute overall line at a time including execute line, i got an error message as 'The COUNT function requires 1 argument(s).'

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. `COUNT(Column 1,Column2 ,Column3...)` will not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'SELECT';
DECLARE @table_name nvarchar(256) = N'YourTableName'

SELECT @sql = @sql + ' COUNT(*)-COUNT(' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) + ') as '+ QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) + N','
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = N'dbo'
  AND TABLE_NAME = @table_name

SET @sql = LEFT(@sql, LEN(@sql) - 1) + ' from ' + @table_name

EXEC (@sql)
```

**Added**

Allright, so here's an example on how to use something alike to for each column calculate the number of values that have at least one duplicate:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'WITH duplicates AS (SELECT';
DECLARE @table_name nvarchar(256) = N'YourTableName';

SELECT @sql = @sql 
  + N' CASE WHEN COUNT(' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) 
  + N') OVER (PARTITION BY ' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) 
  + N') > 1 THEN ' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME)  
  + N' END as '+ QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) + N','
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = N'dbo'
  AND TABLE_NAME = @table_name;

SET @sql = LEFT(@sql, LEN(@sql) - 1) + ' from ' + @table_name + ') SELECT';

SELECT @sql = @sql 
  + N' COUNT(DISTINCT ' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) 
  + N') as '+ QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) + N','
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = N'dbo'
  AND TABLE_NAME = @table_name;

SET @sql = LEFT(@sql, LEN(@sql) - 1) + ' from duplicates';

EXEC (@sql);
```

You see that it uses 2 SELECT statements, the first creates a CTE that replaces all values that have no duplicate with NULL:

```
CASE WHEN COUNT([C1]) OVER (PARTITION BY [C1]) > 1 THEN [C1] END as [C1]
```

The second uses a COUNT DISTINCT to count what is left. Doing it this way, the value NULL will not be counted.

Comment: Good use of `QUOTENAME` always deserved praise! You did, however, forget it at the end `' from ' + @table_name` (which is possibly the most important place, if `@table_name` is an input parameter). ;)

Comment: @Larnu Thanks! To be honest, I didn't forget it, I left it out on purpose, because the table name is probably the only "known" thing and is entered manually, at least in the script. But you are right, if passed as a parameter, it totally makes sense. :-)

Comment: @WolfgangKais, similar to this, if i need to find the count of each column's duplicate data using dynamic query. How to do that? and is it possible?.. I try to do with the above provided sample but it didn't work. I am using Group By for each column , which is not a correct solution to do that.Below is an example of  a syntax shown while executing Print command ...example SELECT[C1], COUNT([C1]) as [id]FROM table_name GROUP BY [C1] HAVING COUNT([C1] )>1 ,[C2], COUNT([C2]) as [c2]FROM table_name GROUP BY [c2] HAVING COUNT([c2] )>1 .... Kindly suggest some solution for it as well.

Comment: @Promila The above query creates one single row. Should the "count of duplicates" also produce one single row? If so, then what will a "duplicate number" of 20 for column C1 mean to you? It could mean one value that is contained 20 times or 10 values with one duplicate each (or anything in between). Or do you want to see 1 or 10 instead (the number of values that have at least one duplicate)? I suggest to first get clear about some "specification" for the calculation for one column. Then, we can find out whether it makes sense to do the same for multiple columns in just one query.

Comment: @WolfgangKais I require the count of duplicate data for each value of a column. I am not sure whether it is possible in a single query..

Comment: @Promila I just added an example for what you described first (`GROUP BY [C1] HAVING COUNT([C1] )>1`). If now you want to count the number of duplicates for each value, please try to imagine how this could be displayed in in a query result (just the way it should *look*, not the way it's *done*). If you were able to do so, please let me know, because I can't.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TempDb..#MissingList') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #MissingList

CREATE TABLE #MissingList
(
    SeqNo INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(255),
    COLUMN_NAME VARCHAR(255),
    MissingCount INT DEFAULT(0)
)

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT
    @SQL = REPLACE(REPLACE(L.List,'&#x0D',''),';','')
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            '
            INSERT INTO #MissingList(TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,MissingCount)
            SELECT TABLE_NAME = ''['+LTRIM(RTRIM(TABLE_SCHEMA))+'].['+LTRIM(RTRIM(TABLE_NAME))+']'',COLUMN_NAME = '''+LTRIM(RTRIM(COLUMN_NAME))+''',MissingCount = COUNT(1) - COUNT(['+LTRIM(RTRIM(COLUMN_NAME))+'])
            FROM ['+LTRIM(RTRIM(TABLE_SCHEMA))+'].['+LTRIM(RTRIM(TABLE_NAME))+']' AS [text()]
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            FOR XML PATH('')
    )L(LIST)

EXEC(@SQL)

SELECT
    *
    FROM #MissingList
```

Comment: Using `'`[` + @Variable + ']'` doesn't stop injection, or handle poorly named objects (there are objects out there with a right bracket `]` in them, trust me). `QUOTENAME` is a far better option.